# JSF Tag disables css preferences for Log Out button

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf

```
<li><h:form styleClass="logoutbuttonform"><h:commandLink action="#{loginController.logout}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i>Log Out</h:commandLink></h:form></li>
```

So my Problem is, I just implemented the functionality of the Logout Button on my Software. But when i add "h:form" the button gets tight and seems to ignore the CSS Preferences of

. [Logout Button with Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T572k.png)

When I remove the JSF Tag, the Logout Button looks normal. why is it that the JSF tag disables the CSS Preferences?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you add a `styleClass` attribute to your `commandLink` *(just as you did in your form tag)* and change the style of the class in your CSS.

Something like this:

```
<li>
  <h:form styleClass="logoutbuttonform">
    <h:commandLink action="#{loginController.logout}" styleClass="yourClass">
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i>
      Log Out
    </h:commandLink>
  </h:form>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.yourClass {
  /* Your CSS */
}
```

References:

1. [TutorialsPoint reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_commandlink_tag.htm)
2. [This thread here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000973iIAA)

Hope this helps